# servicemix: on which port is my osgi bundle listening?

Tags: osgi, port, apache-karaf, spring-restcontroller, apache-servicemix

As a newby to servicemix/karaf, I'm trying to create a very simple program that accepts and returns a REST-request. The class I have is:

```
package (....)

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import (...).model.RSDocument;
import (...).model.RSDocumentResponse;

@RestController
public class DocumentService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/document", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<RSDocumentResponse> printDocument(
            @RequestBody RSDocument documentRequest)
    {
        System.out.println(documentRequest.getContent());
        RSDocumentResponse response = new RSDocumentResponse();
        response.setSuccess(true);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

I've got something similar working in Tomcat. In Tomcat, you would specify the port where it will listen to incoming requests by doubleclicking on the server in eclipse and setting a value in the "Ports" section. How do I set the port in Servicemix, or even figure out which port it's currently listening to? I have the bundle succesfully starting from the command line in Servicemix. My application doesn't seem to be listening on 80 (Apache), 8080 (None), or 8181 (Servicemix console)

Comment: How do you package and deploy your application. I guess you have more than this one class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure you have the web-container deployed. For this make sure the war feature is installed.

```
feature:list | grep war
```

if it's not installed, install it by issueing:

```
feature:install war
```

Now, make sure your jar/war contains the ***Web-ContextPath*** Manifest entry telling the web-container which context path to look for. If you have all other required bundles installed and running, including all dependencies are set you should be able to navigate to your rest service on:

```
 localhost:8181/myContextPath/rest/document
```

Comment: Maybe it is worthwhile pointing out that Karaf relies on Jetty as a web-container and that the configuration, like the port of the connectors, can be changed via the jetty.xml in $KARAF_HOME/etc.

Comment: @Ralf, that's actually only half the truth ... as it's a OSGi Http Service the prefered way of configuring it is to use the osgi service properties:    

org.osgi.service.http.port

Comment: also see: http://ops4j.github.io/pax/web/SNAPSHOT/User-Guide.html#basic-configuration

Comment: I don't have a manifest file, we also don't have that in another (working) project. Can I include Web-ContextPath somewhere else? Maybe blueprint.xml or pom.xml?

Comment: Never mind, I've got it working now, without the contextpath